# Unable to give player custom splash potion

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a custom splash potion but whenever I give it to myself it gives me a splash uncraftable potion.

What am I doing wrong?
The command I'm using is:

```
/give @p minecraft:splash_potion{tag:{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:2,Amplifier:3,Duration:12000},{Id:4,Amplifier:10,Duration:12000},{Id:9,Amplifier:10,Duration:12000},{Id:15,Amplifier:10,Duration:12000},{Id:17,Amplifier:3,Duration:12000},{Id:18,Amplifier:10,Duration:12000},{Id:19,Amplifier:2,Duration:12000},{Id:20,Amplifier:1,Duration:12000}],display:{Name:"Potion Of Guilt"}}}
```

I am playing Minecraft 1.14.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for using the `/give` command with NBT does not include the `tag` tag.

```
/give @p minecraft:splash_potion{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:2,Amplifier:3,Duration:12000},{Id:4,Amplifier:10,Duration:12000},{Id:9,Amplifier:10,Duration:12000},{Id:15,Amplifier:10,Duration:12000},{Id:17,Amplifier:3,Duration:12000},{Id:18,Amplifier:10,Duration:12000},{Id:19,Amplifier:2,Duration:12000},{Id:20,Amplifier:1,Duration:12000}],display:{Name:"Potion Of Guilt"}}
```